# How to put object to S3 via CloudFront

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'd like to upload image to S3 via CloudFront.
If you see the document about CloudFront, you can find that cloud front offers put method for uploading to cloudFront
There could be someone to ask me why i use the cloud front for uploading to S3 
If you search out about that, you can find the solution

What i wanna ask is whether there is method in SDK for uploading to cloud front or not 
As you know , there is method "putObejct" for uploading directly to S3 but i can't find for uploading cloud front ...

please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data can be sent through Amazon CloudFront to the back-end "origin". This is used for using a POST on web forms, to send information back to web servers. It can also be used to [POST data to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html).

If you would rather use an SDK to upload data to Amazon S3, there is no benefit in sending it "via CloudFront". Instead, use the Amazon S3 APIs to upload the data directly to S3.

So, bottom line:

- If you're uploading from a web page that was initially served via CloudFront, **send it through CloudFront to S3**
- If you're calling an API, **call S3 directly**

Comment: OP didn't get around to mentioning it, but the aurguable/theoretical benefit in uploading through CloudFront is to get the traffic into Amazon's high-bandwidth, low-latency network as close to the end user as possible, potentially improving connection quality, stability, performance.  With the CloudFront edge operating as a TCP proxy, retries related to the end user's Internet connection quality would be handled more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If the bucket's region is far away from the uploading computer you can upload faster by enabling S3 Accelerate which uploads directly through the Amazon server located closest to you and then continues sending the file from there to the bucket's actual region at an optimal route.

Have a look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration-examples.html).