# How to upload a file directly to Amazon Cloud Front using Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I just configured an Amazon Cloud Front distribution, and connected it to an existent Amazon S3 bucket. Having said that, this bucket holds 10GB to 40GB video files, and I want to use CF to make the upload process faster (also the download, but the upload is more important in this case).

Finally, I created a simple JS script to push a file to this bucket connected to CF:

```
var AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "111",
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "222",
S3_BUCKET = "videos.company.com",
S3_KEY = "remote_filename.mkv",
fs = require('fs'),
AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY});

var startDate = new Date().toUTCString();

var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/test.mkv');
fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
});  
fileStream.on('open', function () {
  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  s3.putObject({
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: S3_KEY,
    Body: fileStream
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
      console.log('Uploaded file to ' + S3_KEY + ' at ' + new Date().toUTCString());
      console.log("Start time: " + startDate + ", end time: " + new Date().toUTCString());
    }
  }).on('httpUploadProgress', function(progress) {
    console.log('Upload', progress.loaded, 'of' , progress.total, 'bytes' + " --> " + ((progress.loaded*100)/progress.total).toFixed(2) + "%");
  });
});
```

After running the script, I did not notice any speed changes (upload with and without CF distribution)... actually the upload time for both cases are exactly the same. However, after reading some forums, I saw people talking about doing a POST request using the CF url.

How can I upload a file from my server to CF directly?

Thanks!

Comment: I must say that GET os working perfectly, and that I also enables POST/PUT on CF.

Comment: I'm guessing Amazon has better connections than you and I have, so the upload is probably limited by your upload speed, not Amazons, and I thought Cloud Front was a CDN for you content, i.e for downloads, not uploads ?

Comment: You are uploading directly to S3 here, so the fact that you have CloudFront in front of that S3 bucket is totally irrelevant to your upload speed.  You might want to look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394768/how-to-put-object-to-s3-via-cloudfront

Comment: @adeneo the title of the question is misleading.  You can't upload **to** ("into") CloudFront, but you can upload **through** CloudFront, which can provide improved throughput back to the origin server because of the optimized, AWS-controlled network between CloudFront edges and the origin (S3 in this case), and because the TCP session from the browser stops at the CloudFront edge, with a second connection upstream "behind" CloudFront. Your upload tends to traverse less distance "on the Internet" and more distance "on AWS."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are correct on that. Do you know how can a POST an imaging through Cloud Front? Would you have a code snippet?

Comment: You have apparently already changed the Allowed HTTP Methods in the CloudFront distribution to the option that includes `PUT` (default is `GET` and `HEAD` only) ... so, next, generate the signed URL for S3 as normal, but then edit/modify the generated URL to use the CloudFront hostname instead of the bucket hostname and see what happens.  It has been a while since I tinkered with this, so it may be more complicated than that, but this also might be all you need.

Comment: Hey @Michael-sqlbot, I am doing the request using cloud front as the bucket URL.. but it it giving me some CORS erros.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/HASH.cloudfront.net/key1/key2/56d9d500b…L6ZH5KBADA&Expires=222222&Signature=22222. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://local-admin.app.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Comment: The upload directly to S3 is working just fine (removing the Cloud Front and using the bucket URL). Also, I added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin * to Cloud Front (and it is also in the bucket CORS).

Comment: Ok, the right way to do it is calling https://asdasdasda.cloudfront.net/KEY... even like that, PUT does not work. I can get files inside the bucket, but doing a PUT returns a 403 (Forbidden)